# Why do $x^2+y^2=\left(3+2i\right)^2$ and $x^2+y^2=25$ give the same circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Maybe I just been up for too long but I just cant get why:

$$x^2+y^2=\left(3+2i\right)^2$$

and

$$x^2+y^2=25$$

give the exact same circle, why aren't the graphs different?

Shouldn't the second one mean that the radius is the distance from $(3,2i)$ to the centre which here is the origin, $\sqrt{13}$?

---

(From comment) I found it in this: 
$$\int_{|z+1−i|=1+i}\left|z^2\right|dz$$
I was just trying to visualize the contour, when I got stuck, maybe I am overlooking something basic.

Comment: You **can't** have "i" as the radius of a circle in the complex plane.  *Distances", even in the complex plane, are *real* numbers.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could re-express the second equation as $x^2 + y^2 = (3 $x-units$ + 2 $y-units$)^2$. If you think of it like that, then the first equation is identical to it with $i$ being a "y-unit".

Comment: @user247327 I found it in this: $\int_{ |z+1-i|=1+i}|z^2| dz$ I was just trying to visualize the contour, when I got stuck, maybe I am overlooking something basic.

Comment: To emphasize the basic misunderstanding, they do not give the exact same circle. And while your notation is a bit unclear, if you want $z = x+yi$, where $x$ and $y$ are both real numbers, then the graph of the first equation is the empty set.

Comment: Why do you think they give the same circle? They don't. For example, $(0, 5)$ satisfies the second equation but not the first.

Comment: The first equation can be written as $x^2 + y^2  = 5 + 12i$, which doesn't make sense since $x^2 + y^2$ is real and $5 + 12i$ is complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understand, don't you, that the **absolute value** of a complex number is a non-zero **real** number?  "|z+ 1- i|= 1+ i" is impossible!